# Is there a way to maintain lambda concurrency from SQS while maintaining serial execution

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sqs

I have a path from sqs to lambda. Lambda code has some time taking preprocessing before doing actual work.
The issue is,

1. For example, at time 0 a message comes to sqs and then onto start executing in lambda. Suppose it needs 2 units of time for warmup and execution. It will complete at time 2.
2. Now, at time 1 another message comes, as lambda 1 is busy another lambda spins up. It again needs 2 units of time. It will complete at time 3.
3. Here comes the issue, if at time 2.01 another message comes, it will picked by lambda 1 as it has finished work at time 2. Suppose lambda 1 finishes again at 2.99

The final execution sequence is 1,3,2 when it was supposed to be 1,2and 3.

Is there a way to not sacrifice concurrency while maintaining serial order.
Note: Lambda finishes job with a dynamo db write.

Comment: Are you using SQS fifo if order is important to you?

Comment: the problem is because of lambda. The execution time is deciding which gets completed first even if sqs sends messages in order

Comment: Its not a problem of lambda. Standard SQS does not grantee any order. So by the time your messages get to lambda, they maybe be already out of order. Only SQS FIFO can fix that.

Comment: ok, assume its fifo. now how will you explain the sequence i have said

Comment: Such sequence is not possible with fifo.

Comment: leave it, you are not getting my point. thanks for your efforts

Comment: @user8895045 - you were given good advice. Try to understand it and not reject it.